# torch.cuda.is_available() return False? python3.6.4 pytorch1.8.0 torchvsion0.9

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, torch

After I

```
pip install torch-1.8.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

pip install torchvision-0.9.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

And I source the .bashrc:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/cuda/cuda-10.2/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CUDA_HOME=/home/cuda/cuda-10.2:$CUDA_HOME
export PATH=/home/cuda/cuda-10.2/bin:$PATH
```

still get the problems below:
1.`torch.cuda.is_available()` return False
2.`import torch.utils.cpp_extensio` and get: `No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='/home/cuda/cuda-10.2:`

Other Information:

1.

```
NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2  
-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:18:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   58C    P0    30W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:5E:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   58C    P0    29W /  70W |  10047MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:AF:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   68C    P0    76W /  70W |   8746MiB / 15109MiB |     59%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:D8:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   66C    P0    67W /  70W |   8746MiB / 15109MiB |      6%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A
```

2. 

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

I don't knoe how to solve it, does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `conda` because it will install the CUDA runtime for you so you don't need to bother yourself with this kind of problem. See https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Example:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the reason for this problem is: cuda version and pytorch version do not match.

Comment: My cuda version is 10.2, and 11.2 is cuda driver version. I think the versions of CUDA Driver Version and CUDA Runtime Version don't have to be the same, but CUDA Runtime Version should be <=CUDA Driver Version

Comment: Maybe you can try installing a later version of torch? For example, 1.9.0 and 1.10.0, my current configuration is cuda 10.2+torch 1.10.1.